# Custom Post type as Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field

I have a custom post type "issue" and relationship with custom post type "article". What I want is, to create the issue cpt as a taxonomy for the article cpt, and showing it in article post list. When the users add new issue, so the taxonomy will updated it self. And the final result is, I can filtering the articles only based on the issue name.

Anyone can help?﻿

Comment: First create Taxonomy named 'Issues' for CPT 'Article'.
The try this plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-switcher/
With this you can convert all your 'Issues' to 'Articles'. And while doing that select these articles to newly created taxonomy 'Issues'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solutions for this, finally i filtering the custom post type by custom type no need to create or converted post type to taxonomy :)

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like `issues` should be a [custom taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) rather than a custom post type.

Comment: Is there a way to convert a custom post type issue to custom taxonomy without lost the data, or I should create the custom taxonomy and re-input the data again.

Comment: is near from my case post by @strap1 here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128622/creating-a-relationship-between-two-post-types/128626#128626 nice hack actually but my question, is you did filtering your post by artist (new CPT) on admin post list table. because I have same issue with you, and following your hack code. but I need more features to filtering (example from your case)Filtering Album post type using the Artist post type.

Thanks

Comment: If you convert content from a post to a category, you could not retain all the data, no. A taxonomy term would not have a place to store post content, for example. Terms have names, slugs, and descriptions.