# Question about link two types of data in wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, taxonomy

I have a problem and I'd a like a suggestion to solve it. I have two data(Architects and Projects) where both need to link each other, architects must have their own page as well as an archive page. projects must have a page must have an architect

how do I solve this problem? I already thought about make archtects as taxonomy but it wouldn't work because I need an archive and a single page for archtects which will list all projects for this architect.

look at the examples below:

[image: Architects page(and a list of architects)]

[image: Single Architect Page(and a list of projects)]

[image: Single Project Page]

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have already created custom post types for Architects and Projects. In order to make a relation between them you may follow any of the methods below:
a.) Using ACF:

1. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/bidirectional-relationships/

b.) Using Toolset:

1. https://toolset.com/2018/07/how-to-create-post-relationships-between-your-custom-post-types-and-how-to-display-them/

c.) Using Posts to Posts plugin (Use it at your own risk as the plugin hasn't been tested with the latest 3 major releases of WordPress)

1. https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/

d.) Using metabox code by user @vmassuchetto

[How do I create a relationship between two custom post types?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128622/how-do-i-create-a-relationship-between-two-custom-post-types)