# Multi-page posts: A subdirectory for each post?

Tags: theme-development, cms

I am using Wordpress as a CMS and would like to add a 'Learn More' page to each post that is created within a particular category. For example, when

```
http://www.mysite.com/cat/slug
```

is created, I would also like for

```
http://www.mysite.com/cat/slug/learn-more
```

to be created, too.

Ideally, this 'learn more' page would run on a template layout that I would create, and have it's content populated by a custom field within the main post.

Is this at all possible? Is there a plugin available that will allow me to achieve this?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use wordpress post tab plugin,

Else

Need some rewrite rules to do it,

refer these posts 
[Integrating a custom post type into a page hierarchy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13308/integrating-a-custom-post-type-into-a-page-hierarchy) 
[How to handle a hierarchy with custom post types](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2839/how-to-handle-a-hierarchy-with-custom-post-types)

Comment: Thanks, I've just had a quick look at the Post Tab plugin and it seems to be along the right lines!